# Why's the syntax different between these two arrays in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, developer-tools

They both contain the same values, but I'm wondering why they look different when I console them out in Dev tools.

[image]

```
var values = [6, 6, 6, 19, 13, 50]; 

function boxWidth() {
    var widths = new Array();
    widths.push(values);
    console.log(widths);
    console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you're asking why `widths` is `[Array(6)]` but `values` is `[6,6,6,19,13,50]`?

Comment: "*They both contain the same values*" - well no, they don't. Click the inspect button (grey triangle) to see how they differ.

Comment: To clarify. one looks like -> `[6,6,6,19,13,50]` and the other looks like `[[6,6,6,19,13,50]]`  if that help you see the difference..

Comment: thats obviously a nested array read more about stacks in JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `widths` array is an array that has a single member referencing the `values` array, whereas `values` is an array of 6 numbers.

To copy the numbers in individually, do this:

```
widths.push(...values);
```

Or do it when you create the array:

```
var widths = [...values];
```

Or to be legacy compatible:

```
var widths = values.slice();
```

You can serialize the arrays to get a clearer view.

```js
var values = [6, 6, 6, 19, 13, 50]; 

function boxWidth() {
    var widths = new Array();
    widths.push(values);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(widths));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
} 

boxWidth();
```

Comment: Thanks, totally understand now. Was a bit confused. I see that I had an array inside an array, does that make sense?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what you had. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`values` is a 1-dimensional array containing 6 numbers.

`widths` is a 2-dimensional array. Its first dimension is a single element, which is a reference to `values`. The second dimension is the 6 numbers in `values`.

`console.log()` only displays the first dimension in detail by default. You can click on the disclosure triangle of `widths` to see the contents of the inner dimension. If you change it to log JSON, you'll see the full structure of each. Then you'll see the extra level of nesting in `widths`.

```js
var values = [6, 6, 6, 19, 13, 50]; 

function boxWidth() {
    var widths = new Array();
    widths.push(values);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(widths));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
} 

boxWidth();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I just did, thanks for clearing that up for me.